# Can't find etc folder to handle hadoop configuration

Tags: linux, hadoop

I should configure hadoop by going to /usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/
 and editing hadoop-env.sh to add this line:

```
export JAVA_HOME='/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_60'
```

but i can't find etc folder in /usr/local/hadoop

[image: screenshot of terminal]

Comment: is the file in /etc/hadoop instead, maybe?

Answer (score 6):

You probably using hadoop-src , if that case you need to build it first.

else use binary version which is per-compiled, there you can find etc folder.

http://www-eu.apache.org/dist/hadoop/common/hadoop-2.9.0/

download hadoop-2.9.0.tar.gz this or whatever version you need but not source ( src )

Comment: The link you posted is not working anymore, use https://hadoop.apache.org/releases.html to download (download the binary version to get the pre-compiled one)